# How to create a list of small values out of large values

Tags: python, list, sorting

My program currently takes a user input (`"hello"`). It then saves the length of the input (`5`), and creates a list out of the ordinance values e.g:

```
list = []
word = "hello"
for i, item in enumerate(word):
    list.append(ord(word[i]))
```

This gives me a list as such: `[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]`.

From this output I want to try and get `[1, 0, 2, 3, 4]`

I want to try and increased the 'count' if you will, even if the number is repeated. Hopefully this is a bit more clear, sorry it is quite hard to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Another example would be "`@test123`" which would give a list:

`[64, 116, 101, 115, 116, 49, 50, 51, 64]`

The output I want would be: `[4, 8, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3]`. I'm not actually sure if this is achieveable or not, but it would be good if I can manage it.

Comment: If you want to get `0` to `n-1` (n = the length of the string): `range(len(word))`

Comment: So you just want a list of indices? Why?

Comment: do you want `[0, 1, 2, 2, 3]` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to sort the list like that originally, I've changed it to how I want the result, I want to try and get an unsorted list, but from 0-x rather than 101-x or something

Comment: `@test123` should produce `[64, 116, 101, 115, 116, 49, 50, 51]`. Do you mean `@test123@`? Beside that, why does the first `64` is ranked(?) lowered than the second `64`?

Comment: Please do not use, or get in the habit of using, `list` as a name.  Using Python keywords, statements, object names as *identifiers* is bad juju - it *overwrites* their meaning and can cause hard to troubleshoot errors in your code later on.

Comment: I imagine that when you are able to explain in words the *transformation/operation* you are trying to apply to the input then it will be easier for you to code it.  With ```hello``` as the input, how does `104` become `1`,  how does `101` become `0` and how does `108` become `2`, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> list(np.argsort(np.argsort(list('hello'))))
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(np.argsort(np.argsort(list('cadeb'))))
[2, 0, 3, 4, 1]
```

---

If using a third-party module is not an option, use following `argsort`:

```
>>> def argsort(xs):
...     return sorted(range(len(xs)), key=xs.__getitem__)
...
>>> argsort(argsort('hello'))
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
>>> argsort(argsort('cadeb'))
[2, 0, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Using a third party module is not an option sadly, this looks perfect thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
l = []
word = "hello"
for i, item in enumerate(word):
    l.append(ord(word[i]))
    sorted(range(len(l)), key=lambda x:l[x])
```

**output**

```
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: That works quite well, however it gets a bit confused then the values drop below 100.
eg. "cadeb" gives a list 
    `[99, 97, 100, 101, 98]`
however when sorted it gives 
    `[1, 4, 0, 2, 3]`

Comment: can be reduced to: `sorted(range(len(word)), key=word.__getitem__)`